# Syncing database online to html5 offline database storage

Tags: database, html

I have a database that I want to sync to a local database on the client side using html5 webDb. (http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)

I have a couple questions:

- What is the best way to accomplish this sync (I am using php + mysql)
- What browsers support a database on the client side

Comment: What kind of syncing do you want? Will the data only need to be synced one way, eg. from remote to client, or will it require to be synced both ways? If both ways, how do you want to handle collisions where a record has been modified in both ends?

Comment: hmm, I didn't think this far into it yet, but I would imagine there would be 2 way syncing.

Answer (score 0):

- The best way would be to make a dump with a conversion from MySQL to SQLite
- Support can be tracked here http://www.caniuse.com/#search=web%20sql%20database

Just keep in mind that the Web SQL Database spec is no longer maintained (as mentioned on the link in your post). And probably support for it by browser vendors implementing it now might be dropped in the future.